# Exchange 2007 Online Maintenance Overlap

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, maintenance

Every night at 02:59 the following events are logged by my Exchange server:

```
Event Type:   Warning Event
Source:       MSExchangeIS Mailbox Store
Event Category:  Background Cleanup 
Event ID:       9871 
Date:           5/20/2009
Time:           2:59:59 AM 
User:           N/A
Computer:       EXCHFC2 
Description: There is an online maintenance overlap for database "First Storage Group\Mailbox Database". Please revise the online maintenance schedule.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

.

```
Event Type: Information
Event Source:   ESE
Event Category: Online Defragmentation 
Event ID:   704
Date:       5/20/2009
Time:       2:59:59 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   EXCHFC2
Description:
MSExchangeIS (12420) First Storage Group: Online defragmentation of database 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\Mailbox\First Storage Group\Mailbox Database.edb' was interrupted and terminated. The next time online defragmentation is started on this database, it will resume from the point of interruption. 

For more information, click http://www.microsoft.com/contentredirect.asp.
```

This is Exchange 2007 running on Windows 2003 x64.

Here's my Exchange maintenance schedule:

```
First Storage Group\Mailbox Database: 20:00 - 03:00  
Second Storage Group\Public Folder Database: 03:00 - 06:00
```

Note that I tried spacing them out more (First ended at 2, second started at 4) to no avail. The error message always appears a second before completion of the First Storage Group's maintenance plan.

The interrupted defragmentation noted in that second event was begun at 02:15. Another defragmentation of the exact same database was begun at 23:04 and finished at 02:08. Immediately before this full defragmentation, the interrupted one from last night was completed.

So it's as if the system is defragging the database in a loop, then complaining when that defrag is interrupted by the conclusion of the maintenance window.

How can I fix this behavior?

**EDIT**

My backups run at 06:30. There are no scheduled jobs on this machine.

The Best Practices Analyzer reports nothing relevant.

I understand that this is not a critical error, but I'm concerned that if I simply ignore it I'll overlook a future problem when maintenance is NOT being adequately performed. In that vein, I'd like to resolve whatever is causing the defrags to loop during the maintenance window.

Comment: Lets bounty it.

Comment: Only two hours left! Is this beyond all hope?

Answer (score 1):

The 9871 error is thrown when a databases window for maintenance is closed and it is still running transactions. It will complete the maintenance and its more than likely not actually anything to do with running the maintenance on the other database at all, its a pretty badly written error message.

Often this message is triggered when ba backup is running when the maintenance window ends, could this be happening?

It may be worthwhile to run the Exchange Best Practices Analyser against this server just to check if there are any problems it can pick up.

Comment: Answers to these questions added to my original post.

Comment: This answer was auto-selected when the bounty expired. There is some useful information here that will hopefully help others but, unfortunately, it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Sam is right... it is just a poorly written error message.

Event 9871 is logged when the maintenance windows is over for a database, but a transaction is still being processed. Exchange doesn't end the transaction just because it hits the end of the maintenance window, it just logs the 9871.

You can safely ignore the error (or extend the maintenance window if you want to avoid the event being logged).

Comment: Extending the maintenance window does not avoid the event-logging for reasons outlined in my post (ie, it continually restarts).

Answer (score 0):

> So it's as if the system is defragging
>   the database in a loop, then
>   complaining when that defrag is
>   interrupted by the conclusion of the
>   maintenance window.
>
> How can I fix this behavior?

This is working as designed. From: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996226(EXCHG.65).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996226(EXCHG.65).aspx#OnlineDefragmentation)

> It is possible that this process does
>   not complete before the time indicated
>   by the Microsoft Exchange Information
>   Store service. In such a case, the ESE
>   engine stores the last table
>   successfully processed. At the next
>   occurrence of Online Defragmentation,
>   ESE selects the next table in the
>   metadata, and will resume processing
>   tables until the maintenance window
>   ends.. If online defragmentation can
>   process all tables before the
>   maintenance window ends, it will
>   restart at the first table listed in
>   the metadata and loop on all tables
>   until the maintenance window ends. The
>   changes made to the database are
>   transacted. Therefore, a large number
>   of delete operations, followed by an
>   online defragmentation cycle, will
>   generate a large number of transaction
>   logs, because records are compressed
>   into the fewest number pages.

Which means that it will loop through the databases during the maintenance windows.

As for the Maintenance Overlap message, the suggested is posted here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995795.aspx

> By default, the mailbox store maintenance processes run nightly from 1:00 A.M. to 5:00 A.M. Because of the server resources required for the maintenance processes, it is recommended that you modify the maintenance schedules so that the mailbox stores have schedules that differ by at least 15 minutes.

So according to that if you start the Second Storage Group maintenance window at 3:15 instead of 3:00 the message will go away.

Comment: From my original post: "Note that I tried spacing [the maintenance schedules] out more (First ended at 2, second started at 4) to no avail. The error message always appears a second before completion of the First Storage Group's maintenance plan." I appreciate the confirmation that this is working as expected, but my goal is to fix the error message.